# How can I move two contents on two different positions on nested html strucuture?

Tags: css, css-position

I have this nested HTML structure

```
<div class="object-tile-container">
    <div class="object-tile-container">
      <div class="object-tile-main-content">
        <div class="left-block">
          <div class="left-block-custom">
            <img class="stretch"" src="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="middle-block">
          <div class="version-number">2</div>
          <div class="other-content">some other content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-block">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this CSS

```
.object-tile-container {
  background-color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 510px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: calc(240px + 10px);
    height: calc(240px + 10px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.object-tile-main-content {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%
}

.object-tile-container {
  background-color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 510px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: calc(240px + 10px);
    height: calc(240px + 10px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.object-tile-container .left-block {
  max-width: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.object-tile-container .left-block .left-block-custom {
  text-align: initial;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.object-tile-container .left-block .stretch {
  object-fit: fill;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


.object-tile-container .middle-block {
  max-width: 290px;
  min-width: 290px;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

it look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/400gY.png)

the problem I am facing is moving the `2` at the top left corner where the image is placed, and the `other content` at the bottom

I want to note that this html and css is from third party dependency, and the only wat to insert values are in the middle-block.

So in the middle-block I have two contents and I am having problems to place them on correct positions: Needs to look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcguc.png)

I tried first  adding position:relative on middle-block and position absolute on the content that I want to place

```
.middle-block {
  position: relative;
}

.other-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

now other-content is down at the bottom
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg9cm.png)

but I do not see other way how can I place now the number `2` at the top left corner, because when I place position:absolute

```
.version-number {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
```

the number two is left but only on the `middle-block` div because `middle-block` has `position:relative` and any `absolute` position we have on the children of `middle-block` will be on that div but not on the left-block.

How can I solve this  ?
With my CSS or modifying the existing CSS ?

Comment: using relative and absolute position is not an ideal choice here. You could use grid. Do you know how to use grid?